# Can rough in shower drain be offset below grade?

Tags: plumbing, basement, framing

Dug out the drain box for my basement shower/tub drain. It's about 2" off from where the tub drain will line up. I need it to b 14 5/8 from the stud wall per the installation instructions for a 30" tub. The pipe in the floor is 17" away from the wall right now.

Can the plumber offset the drain/trap to line up, or would it be better to move the wall closer to the drain?

[image]

Comment: is there a trap going on there or does it lead to a floor trap?   most traps offer quite a lot of adjustment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the J bend is not in place yet the pipe will need to be cut back to add it. Then with that in place the drain can be lined up to the right spot.

That blocked out portion of concrete is just for that purpose, get the pipe close, then fine tune it when the final hook up happens.

Comment: nothing attached yet. All I did was dig out the gravel/concrete on top of it so I don't have to pay the plumber to do it.